# Powershell Add-content Out-File Text is wrong

Tags: powershell, file, logging, spaces

When i use this:

```
"$LogTime $CurrentDate Invalid Archive Grouping selected. You selected '$ArchiveGrouping'" | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
```

To write to a file i generated with this code:

```
$Logdate = Get-Date
$Logname = $Logdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt"
Add-Content -Path C:\ArchiveStorage\$Logname "Log" -force
$LogFile = "C:\ArchiveStorage\$Logname"
```

The Text in the file looks weird it looks like this:
[image]

if i change the code to just write to an existing file like:

```
$LogFile = "C:\ArchiveStorage\Log.txt"
```

The text file is as it should be:
[image]

why does it make spaces and all that random crap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been hit by double byte Unicode. When, say, letter `A` is written into the file, there usually is a single byte value `0x41`. In double byte Unicode, the byte value for `A` is `0x0041` or `0x4100` depending on endianess.

When Notepad opens a file that has no Unicode [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it assumes all the extra `00` in file contents are blank spaces. That's why you do see `w e r i d   s p a c i n g`.

For a fix, try using `-Encoding ASCII` parameter with `Add-Content`.

Answer (score 2):

The "Log" entries look different because they were written with Add-Content, which uses a default encoding of ASCII, and Out-File uses a default encoding of Unicode.

Either specify the encoding type on Out-File, or switch to using Add-Content for both the "Log" heading and the detail lines.